# XeLaTeX, fc-list, fc-cache problem

Tags: fonts, fontspec, linux

I'm using XeLaTeX which is based on Linux. The problem is about `fc-cache` and `fc-list`. The problem is the following:

1) I noticed that in the folder `/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm` I have a lot of `.otf` fonts.
2) I know that its name is `Latin Modern Roman`, but doing `fc-list | grep Latin` I cannot find anything;
3) So I update cache doing `fc-cache -fv /usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm`, here it's the result

```
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm: caching, new cache contents: 72 fonts, 0 dirs
/var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/root/.cache/fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
/root/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
```

fc-cache: succeeded

4) however doing again `fc-list | grep Latin` I don't get anything. What is the problem? How can I have that font in my cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I found the solution: it must be added the following file

```
 <?xml version='1.0'?>
 <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
 <fontconfig>
 <dir>/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
 </fontconfig>
```

named `09-texlive.conf` in `/etc/fonts/conf.d`. Of course `09` con be substituted by any number from `00` to `08`.